# Meteor's standard log in form with ipad + chrome

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, authentication, meteor, accounts

Using the standard login form that is provided by accounts + accounts-ui, I am not able to log in through my Ipad 4 device using Chrome (Safari works). It seems to me that the callback is not done at all. Anyone encountered a similar problem? Works on desktop + Windows & Android phone.

The page: http://todoys.meteor.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is already addressed:

https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/09/15/meteor-092-iOS-Android-mobile-apps-phonegap-cordova

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients

Solution lies in detecting the environment and making the login procedure redirect between the pages, instead of opening a new window.